# how to check contains string value in NsmutableArray

Tags: ios, swift, nsmutablearray

i getting some response which contains some information, i stored value in dictionary format in NSMutableArray for example

```
{name : daniel, email : xxx.com},{name: daniel, email : yay.com},{name : daniel, email : zzz.com} {name: Annie, email : annie.com},{name: George, email : ger.com}
```

i have two label Name and Email. when i press Label Action i displayed all the usernames in that i selecting name as "daniel"

Now i going for second label called Email Action in that i want only email list of "daniel" its contains three mail i have to displayed in tableview

here i tried this code but didn't worked for me

```
if NameLabel.text!.containsString(self.NameList.valueForKey("Name") as! String){
             NSLog("success")
        }else{
            NSLog("fail")
        }
```

my output log :

```
Could not cast value of type '__NSArrayI' (0x1059da8b0) to 'NSString' (0x103a50b20).
```

Comment: Please do not edit your question to include a new problem. Instead, create a new question.

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
let Namelist = [["name" : "daniel", "email" : "abc@gmail.com"]]

let data = Namelist.filter{($0 as [String:String])["name"]!.lowercaseString.containsString("daniel".lowercaseString)}.map { x in return x["email"]!}
print(data)
```

I have tested it in playground

[image]

Comment: bro i thing u understand the question, in single Array i holding two "Key" called "name" and "email" first i loading value for name list like this detailsArray = self.parkList.valueForKey("Name") as! NSArray

Comment: later while coming to email button i have to display the email ids belongs to the selected user

Comment: its worked. but some case my app gets terminate and showing result Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '-[UITableView _contentOffsetForScrollingToRowAtIndexPath:atScrollPosition:]: row (2) beyond bounds (1) for section (0)

Comment: it has nothing to do with this scenario

Comment: Please check this *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '-[UITableView _contentOffsetForScrollingToRowAtIndexPath:atScrollPosition:]: row (2) beyond bounds (1) for section (0) error.The relevant answer is above my answer.

Comment: but sir you should have ask another question, now you see title and answer is not related and approved answer got rejected

Answer (score 1):

You have a dictionary array that means that you need to loop through the array and then check if each dictionary contains a value for the key 'name' that is equal to your nameLabel text and then get the email from the same dictionary.

```
let nameList : NSMutableArray = [["name":"daniel","email":"daniel@test"], ["name":"martin","email":"martin@test"], ["name":"john","email":"john@test"]]

...
let nameLabel = UILabel()
nameLabel.text = "daniel"
...

for list in nameList {

    if let dic = list as? [String: String] {


        if dic["name"] == nameLabel.text {
            let email = dic["email"]
            print("\(email)")
        }
    }
}
```